# Authenticating with samAccountName in UPN format

Tags: active-directory, ldap

While adding support for authenticating a user via Active Directory using the user's `samAccountName`, I accidentally authenticated with the `samAccountName` in UPN format.

Example:  User has UPN of `test@mycorp.com` the `samAccountName` is `anotherTest`
Note that the `samAccountName` and the UPN are completely different.
When I perform the ldap bind operation with username as `anotherTest@mycorp.com`, the authentication surprisingly succeeds.

Why does it succeed?  Is it valid to bind with a `samAccountName` in UPN format?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Good question.  This has been the case and I have never tried to find an answer.  I couldn't find a document online but just this [discussion](http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/Windows/microsoft.public.windows.server.active_directory/2007-02/msg00114.html) in another forum.

It sounds like there is a default UPN in Active Directory (but not ADAM) regardless of what value you set in the `userPrincipalName` attribute.  The default UPN is in the form of `<samAccountName>@<domainName>`.

You should also note that `userPrincipalName` attribute is not a mandatory attribute.  That means you can always create an AD user object with no value assigned to `userPrincipalName` attribute.  You won't realize that if you are creating it using Active Directory User and Computer snapin because the UI itself forces you always type in the value.  However, if you create an AD object programmatically using ADSI, you are allowed to do that.

If you are old enough to have some experience on NT4 system, you should be aware that there was only samAccountName at that time but no UPN at all.  Exactly because of this, when you do the migration from NT4 to Windows 2003, [you will create a bunch of users with no UPN set to it](http://www.winvistatips.com/after-upgrade-nt-4-0-2003-upn-user-logon-name-missing-t677404.html)

I suspect this was the motivation to have a default UPN derived from `samAccountName`.

Note that `samAccountName` is a mandatory attribute for AD user object.  So, there is no chance that this attribute is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Based on information provided in [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc223499.aspx) it seems normal that samAccourntName@domainName allow successful binding:

> The UPN of an object is either:
>
> - A value of the userPrincipalName attribute of the object, or
> - Only for AD DS: The value of the 
>
>   sAMAccountName attribute of the object, followed by a "@" sign, followed by either:
>
>   - The DNS name
>
>    of a domain in the same forest as the object,
> - or A value in the uPNSuffixes attribute of the Partitions container in the config NCreplica.