# Windows Integrated Authentication with SQL

Tags: sql, authentication, windows-authentication

I have an application that uses passthrough authentication to log into. All the computers are on a domain. When someone logs in and saves settings, it is set to store their settings based on userID. When their userID is being stored, some people's are being stored as DOMAIN\userid while others are being stored as userid@domain.com.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Active Directory

- DOMAIN\userid is the "old" style. 
  In AD, it is `sAMAccountName` and is also known as `pre-Windows 2000 logon name`
- userid@domain.com is the "new" style. In AD, it is `userPrincipalName`

Old is Windows NT, new is Windows 2000+ but the "old" is still commonly used.

More from a [Server Fault answer](https://serverfault.com/q/371150/4955) and also [Authenticating with samAccountName in UPN format](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11527173/27535), If you feel sleepy, here is a [Microsoft blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/openspecification/archive/2009/07/10/understanding-unique-attributes-in-active-directory.aspx)